# Count of rows through Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

All, need a help in a batch file script.

I have .txt file, the main purpose is to get the count of the file and if count is more than 1000 then create a .txt file otherwise finish the script.

I have a command in batch file as below;-

```
@echo on

cd C:\Windows\System32

type C:\Testfolder\Samplefile.txt| find "" /v /c
```

This gives me count of 1400. Now I need to include "When the count is >1000 then create a blank.txt file in a specific path otherwise dont do anything just complete the script.

Any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a FOR /F command to capture the output of the FIND command.

```
@echo off
FOR /F "delims=" %%G in ('type C:\Testfolder\Samplefile.txt^| find /v /c ""') do set count=%%G
IF %count% gtr 1000 type nul>"C:\some path\blankfile.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. But have one more question. Seems like Find /v /c command will work if the batch file is in C:. Our Samplefile.txt is in different server. can we do anything else to make it work.